# Scoping Chef LWRPs back to the cookbook containing the resource being called

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe, lwrp

I have a cookbook that contains a LWRP and some files in the "files" folder.

```
cookbook_file put_it_here do
  source myfile
end
```

A recipe in another cookbook that calls this resource will look in its own cookbook's "files" dir, not the files of the cookbook where the resource is located.

I tried using cookbook_name, but that still resolves to the recipe calling the resource so the code below does not work.

```
cookbook_file put_it_here do
  source myfile
  cookbook cookbook_name
end
```

How can I refer to the files dir of the cookbook the resource is located in without having to hard code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you just have to hard code it.

We don't expose this directly for LWRPs, though you could technically parse it out of `self.class.to_s`. For Poise I've got a thing that reverse-engineers the cookbook name based on manifest data, but that doesn't probably help you unless you want to drink my kool-aid.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, by the way this isn't anti-patterny is it? I suppose I'll look at some other cookbooks, but is this fairly common?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty common and annoying. Which is why I fixed it for all my cookbooks :) I tend to not bother caring about how Chef core does stuff if I can fix it myself.